# How to specify start and end frames when making a video with ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, jupyter-notebook

I am working with python in a jupyter notebook, and I am trying to use ffmpeg to specify the start and end images and convert several images from a folder into a single video. I have a folder, 'images', with the images inside labeled, 'image0', 'image1', 'image2', etc. I would like to specify the start and end images in my video. For example, I would like to be able to make the video using 'image100', to 'image200'. Right now, I have:

```
!/home/jovyan/ffmpeg-dir/ffmpeg -i /home/jovyan/images/image%d.bmp -frames:v 1000 /home/jovyan/output.mp4
```

This is making the video correctly, but I believe it is just taking the first 1000 images.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `-start_number`.

> Use the -start_number option to declare a starting number for the sequence. This is useful if your sequence does not start with img001.jpg but is still in a numerical order.

(source: [https://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#toc-How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f](http://ffmpeg%20documentation))

> For example, I would like to be able to make the video using 'image100', to 'image200'.

You need to combine `-start_number 100` and `-frames:v 101` (101 frames from `image100.jpg` to `image200.jpg`).

Comment: Note that `-start_number 100` has to come before specifying the inputs with `-i`

Answer (score 2):

**You can try this:**

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -ss 00:00:03 -t 00:00:08 -async 1 cut.mp4
```

OR

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -ss 00:00:03 -t 00:00:08 -async 1 -c copy cut.mp4
```

The -t option specifies a duration, not an end time. The above command will encode 8s of video starting at 3s. To start at 3s and end at 8s use -t 5. If you are using a current version of ffmpeg you can also replace -t with -to in the above command to end at the specified time.

Comment: Thanks! Does this crop the current video to be from the third through eighth second?

Comment: does using "-i movie.mp4" after end time,executes command faster?

Comment: This answer is useful, since a search will likely end up here even if the input is a video

Answer (score -1):

I was faced with one task to encode each 60-th frame with jpeg-lossless codec. The yuv-sequence had a fixed frame rate = 60fps. I applied the following `-ss 00:00:01` to access 60-th frame:

```
ffmpeg -pix_fmt yuv420p  -video_size 1920x1080 -r 60 -ss 00:00:01 -i test_1920x1080.yuv -frames:v 1 -vcodec jpegls -pix_fmt yuv420p  -y test_frame60_ls.jpg
```

***Notice:*** Despite explicitly declaring the output as `format = yuv420p`, the format rgb24 was used instead.